# Join Excel file and HTML table with PHPExcel

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I have a "complex" HTML table generated with PHP, with joined cells and rows and different layout row after row.
The table has an header with images so I can't export to Excel with header file specification and I need to use PHPExcel.
The idea is to create an xls file with header and then add rows "from HTML".
A second option (quite better for me) is to save the table as xls file from PHP, then open it with PHPExcel and insert the image.
So, after surfing for hours an testing some example I haven't a solution working.
For example I tried these (that stop at line "ERROR HERE" without output):

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$filename = "DownloadReport";
$table    = $_SESSION['XLS_DATA']; // html formated table

$tmpfile = time().'.html';
file_put_contents($tmpfile, $table);

$objPHPExcel     = new PHPExcel();
$excelHTMLReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
$excelHTMLReader->loadIntoExisting($tmpfile, $objPHPExcel);
// ERROR HERE

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename); 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$writer->save('php://output');

echo unlink($tmpfile);

exit;
?>
```

So I look for some suggestion or some previous useful post.

Comment: Don't instantiate your PHPExcel object and then call `loadIntoExisting()` directly..... just try using `$excelHTMLReader->load($tmpfile);`

Comment: But you say that it gives an error with no output? How do you know that it gives an error then? What is written to PHP or webserver logs? Does it actually stop, or does it simply generate an empty spreadsheet when you call the Reader's save() method?

Comment: @Mark Baker
1) Sorry, but in these way I can alter the $excelHTMLReader object like a $objPHPExcel object? So there is a an "automatic" conversion from an HTML table and an Excel one?
2) I inserted a echo('test') before that line and it appears; if I insert it after nothing come out; the surce code of the resulting page is empty.

Comment: Well the HTML Reader should work with tables and convert them to Excel, that's its purpose.... what about the PHP/Webserver logs? It's very rare for PHP scripts to fail with absolutely no notification at all

Comment: @Mark Baker Nothing on the log :-(

Comment: You dont have an extension on the filename. So your header that uses filename does not have .xlsx

Comment: I've stumbled on the same question, and after studying the PHPExcel source code, I noticed that whenever I load a HTML file that contains a <table> inside, the table is inserted in the beginning of the spreadsheet (row 1 and column 'A'). That seems to be hardcoded in the HTML reader class, and I had no luck to implement a option to customize those values in PHP. However, I created a solution that combines JavaScript with PHP, in order to change <table> DOM data before sending it to PHPExcel, and that worked for me.